# Change payment status buttons gives error "Creating default object..."

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to make 2 buttons with `Mars as Paid` and `Mark as Unpaid` values 1/0.

When I click on button I've got error:

```
Creating default object from empty value
```

What is wrong with the code? I know it can be write more 'intelligent'.
Here is the controller

```
public function ordersPaidSubmit($orderId) {

$order = Order::where('order_id', $orderId)->first();
    if (!$order) {
        App::abort(404);
}
    $paid->paid = Input::get('paid');
    $order->save();

    return Redirect::to('/orders')->with('message', '');
}
```

And here is view buttons

```
{{ Form::open() }}
    @if($order->paid = 0)
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="paid" id="paid" value="1">Mark Order as Paid</button> 
    @else
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="paid" id="paid" value="0">Mark Order as Unpaid</button>
    @endif
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like the problem is in your controller where you take `paid` value from the form. Try to replace:

```
$paid->paid
```

whit

```
$paid['paid']
```

On this line

```
$paid->paid = Input::get('paid');
```